# Android Alert Dialog Force Close

Tags: android, alert

Is there any way to build an Alert Dialog with a Button "Force Close" that close the app?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on you activity life cycle.
If you always finish your activities after starting a new one, you can simply create a dialog with one button and on click of the button, you simply call finish() and thats it.

A general "close the whole application" is not how the life cycle should be used.